# What does "be so much with something" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

I have come across it in the fifth episode of the tenth season of *Friends*. Here is the context:
Friends

> Monica: Hey Rach, the adoption agency needs letters of recommendation
> and we were wondering if you would write one for us.
>
> Rachel: Of course, I'd be honored!
>
> Chandler: Thanks!
>
> Monica: Thank you!
>
> (Joey looks at them, disappointed about their decision)
>
> Joey: U-U-Um, I think there's been an oversight.
>
> Chandler: Joey, we would've asked you, we just thought you wouldn't be
> interested.
>
> Monica: Yeah, it's just we don't think of you as really being **so much
> "with the words**".

Does Monica think Joey isn't good with word or that he doesn't speak much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that they think he is not good with words, i.e. he is not articulate or good at using language in a skillful way.